# Force line to execute before closure

Tags: javascript, closures

I have the following code

```
(function() {
    var weather = new Weather();
    var input = document.getElementById("inputCity");
    var weatherHolder = document.getElementsByClassName("weather");
    var loading = document.getElementById("loadingSign");

    input.focus();

    input.onkeyup = function(e) { 
        if (e.keyCode == 13 && input.value != "") {
            loading.classList.remove("hidden");
            weather.getWeather(input.value, function (returnValue) {
                for (iter in returnValue) {
                    weatherHolder[iter].classList.remove('hidden');
                    document.getElementById("weather" + (parseInt(iter) + 1)).innerHTML = returnValue[iter].date; 
                }
            });
            loading.classList.add("hidden");
        }
    };
})();
```

I want to force the execution of the line `loading.classList.remove("hidden");` before waiting for the closure bellow to complete.

If I remove the closure lines the script works perfectly, however, I can't make it work if the closure fails.

For instance, the code below works perfectly:

```
(function() {
    var weather = new Weather();
    var input = document.getElementById("inputCity");
    var weatherHolder = document.getElementsByClassName("weather");
    var loading = document.getElementById("loadingSign");

    input.focus();

    input.onkeyup = function(e) { 
        if (e.keyCode == 13 && input.value != "") {
            loading.classList.remove("hidden");
            alert("teste");
            loading.classList.add("hidden");
        }
    };
})();
```

The problem is in the line `loading.classList.remove("hidden");` . This is supposed to remove a class that's hiding a message and a spinner. If I replace the closure lines with an alert the spinner shows, however, if I have that closure function the spinner is never shown.

How can I force that line to be called whether the closure is successful or not?

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand the question but judging from the code you have, it would be wiser to add the `loading.classList.add("hidden");` inside the callback so it gets executed correctly.

```
(function() {
    var weather = new Weather();
    var input = document.getElementById("inputCity");
    var weatherHolder = document.getElementsByClassName("weather");
    var loading = document.getElementById("loadingSign");

    input.focus();

    input.onkeyup = function(e) { 
        if (e.keyCode == 13 && input.value != "") {
            loading.classList.remove("hidden");
            weather.getWeather(input.value, function (returnValue) {
                for (iter in returnValue) {
                    weatherHolder[iter].classList.remove('hidden');
                    document.getElementById("weather" + (parseInt(iter) + 1)).innerHTML = returnValue[iter].date; 
                }
                // Here
                loading.classList.add("hidden");
            });
        }
    };
})();
```

Ok so you are asking to "force the execution of..." but in fact what I suspect is happening here is that: the line we moved was not "waiting" on `getWeather` to finish.

Comment: The problem is in the line `loading.classList.remove("hidden");` . This is supposed to remove a class that's hiding a message and a spinner. If I replace the closure lines with an alert the spinner shows, however, if I have that closure function the spinner is never shown.

Comment: The line `loading.classList.add("hidden");` works perfectly, I want to remove the class hidden, in the line I've told in the comment above. It shouldn't depend on the closure to work, right?